# Security in HTTP headers

Tags: http, security

What type of security offer nowadays HTTP headers. I mean apart from the TLS layer,I readed about the digest header using a hash and also headers like HSTS that force to use TLS certificate. My question is  ¿HTTP only offer digest and HSTS or something more?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: I know that HTTP offer security with headers, like I said with the HSTS header but I don't know what type of security offer nowadays